# While creating index, get "Query_shard_exception" in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to send data to Elasticsearch from .Net by using NEST library. 
My ES version is 6.7 and NEST version 6.7 too.

So while creating index I get exception type query_shard_exception `No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on`

I created single node and tried send my message.

```
 var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200/");
 var mysettings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
 var client = new ElasticClient(mysettings);

 var tweet = new {
       Id = 1,
       FirstName = "John",
       LastName = "Grank",
       PostDate = new DateTime(2019,7,12),
       Message = "Trying out NEST, so far so good?"   
}

 var response = client.Index(tweet,idx=> idx.Index(mytweetindex));
```

Do you have any idea what I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: maybe it does not accept datetime type?

Comment: This is the answer from `github`: "But you would also get this error, albeit from a different line, if you don't have a @timestamp field in your actual data. You can change this by setting timestamp_field in the rule to a different field name."

Comment: @GugaNemsitsveridze I changed PostDate with "@timestamp" field ,and again I get same error.

Comment: This seems be an error for search query rather than indexing.

Comment: @NishantSaini I have already send NLog logs to another index. If the query is wrong , then I can not see that index as well , but I see another index and inside. I mean that serach query is work fine.